# No-Cache Refresh In Robot Framework Selenium2Library

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, robotframework

I have a test script written in python robot framework which navigates through a website and tests its pages. The website sometimes needs to refresh all its content from server, i.e. it needs a No-Cache Refresh.

Robot Framework selenium2library has a `reload page` method which simply performs a Refresh-If-Modified. In Python I can use `driver.refresh()` which does the same.

I tried `Press Key` in robot framework and `driver.send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + Keys.F5)` and `driver.get(url)` in python; none of them was successful!

Any idea how to do that??

To clarify, a `No-Cache Refresh`, retrieves all the website data from its server regardless of its changes on the server, but a `Refresh-If-Modified` first sends a request to the server and asks for changes, then it just requests to retrieve modified data.

Comment: which versions are using?

Comment: @Rao, `robotframework-2.9`, `robotframework_selenium2library-1.7.3`, `python2.7`; and my OS is windows 7 - 64 bit version.

Comment: You mean clean browser cache? because you already seemed to tried out refresh page(hoping that worked)

Comment: @Rao, please review my edit.

Comment: Sorry to come back again. What do you mean by `No-Cache Refresh`, `Refresh-Is-Modify`? are these keywords of Selenium2Library which I could not found though in the documentation? I can only find `Reload Page`.

Comment: @Rao, no; they are related to browsers! I can suggest you [this page](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox handle in a different way the cache when robot by selenium launch those browsers.

to be sure browser cache is cleared, i use Close All Browsers keyword because it resets browser cache (http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Close%20All%20Browsers) and then i open the browser again.

so maybe you will use also Delete All Cookies keyword

Answer (score 0):

You could do it through javascript's `location.reload()`, passing `true` to the call - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

```
Execute Javascript    window.location.reload(true);
```

Yet [YMMV](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=window.location.reload%28true%29+not+working) - some browsers try to outsmart it, that's a common problem for the js devs.